# Output of echo $$

Tags: command-line

The output of `echo $$` command displays some number in the standard output like below.

```
$ echo $$
14594
```

What is that number? And also,

```
$ x=a
$ echo $x
a
```

In the above example `echo $x` parses the variable x and displays the value of `x` to the standard output.Likewise in this command `echo $$`, is that the second dollar symbol 
represents any variable?

Answer (score 3):

`$$` is the PID ([process identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)) of the current shell (not subshell). Within a script, inside a subshell, `$$` returns the PID of the script, not the subshell. See [Internal Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID).

You can find also the PID returned by `echo $$` in terminal in the output of the following command:

```
ps ax | grep bash
```

Answer (score 2):

`$$` is one of bash's internal variables. Unlike `$x`, in your example, it does not "contain" a value, the value is requested each time accessing the variable.

**In a bash script,** it returns the process id of the script itself. In a script you can call `kill $$` to send `SIGTERM` to your script.

**In a bash shell,** it returns the process id of the currently running bash process.

**In a bash script, inside a subshell,** it returns the process id of the script, not the subshell.